# Best way to have mutliple countdown timers in a page updated live

Tags: reactjs, timer, socket.io

Alright guys, I have a quick question.
So I have a website I'm developing and It's gonna have multiple matches listed but I want to show the timeout which is 10mins. If the countdown timer finishes the 10mins after it was created, Then it will cancel the game. I don't need help with the actual code to cancel the game or anything like that more just guidance on what would be the best way to do this. I was thinking of using Socket to update the time but thats a lot of communication through socket for just a timer.

Here is a screenshot of an example of what I am shooting for.
https://gyazo.com/f196e4523c36a4887b23349bcd955d36

Thinking of the following. Have a timestamp on the match and a isActive on the match.
When I grab all the games, I will grab only the isActive === true
Then with the timestamp, I will check to see if the time from NOW using MomentJS, compared to the timestamp if it is more than 10mins ( Or whatever our timeout is )
If it  is expired, push an action to update the game is isActive = false
If it is valid, I will grab the remaining time then set a variable of it, then do a setInterval to decrease the time every second. OR even use CountdownJS to create a timer, Since I have a start and end date now.
Start date would be the NOW and the end date would be the start date + timeout time

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are really trying to accomplish two things here:

1. Cancel a match if it has timed out
2. Show on the client a countdown to said time out

I think you have a couple of options here, but I think the simplest solution is likely to use a field like `activeUntil`. When the match is created, you can set a field `activeUntil` to now + however long you want the timeout to be (in this case 10 minutes).

The client would easily be able to display a countdown to that timestamp (using `setInterval` or maybe a library of some sort), and when you are looking for games, you can easily query for games whose `activeUntil` fields are in the future. This makes the cancellation of the game implicitly defined by the `activeUntil` field.

Now if you want to perform some action once the game is no longer active (for example setting a field like `isActive` to false), I think it is best to schedule that sort of thing on the server. If this must be done on the client, you can always do something like this in JavaScript:

```
const onMatchTimeout = () => {
  // Do whatever you like on timeout
  // Dispatch an action, call some code, etc
};

const timeout = Number(new Date()) - Number(activeUntil);
if (timeout >= 0) {
  setTimeout(onMatchTimeout, timeout);
}
```